# On a Stopping Time Argument in Harmonic Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, stopping-times

Quite often there is a common trick in harmonic analysis like the following:

Assume that $0<S(x)<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Consider the set
\begin{align*}
\Omega_{k}&=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}: S(x)>2^{k}\},\\
\mathcal{D}_{k}&=\left\{\text{dyadic cube}~\mathcal{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}:|\mathcal{Q}\cap\Omega_{k}|>\dfrac{1}{2}|\mathcal{Q}|~\text{and}~|\mathcal{Q}\cap\Omega_{k+1}|\leq\dfrac{1}{2}|\mathcal{Q}|\right\},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}
The author claimed without further reasoning that for each dyadic cube $\mathcal{Q}\in\mathcal{D}_{k}$, there is a maximal dyadic cube $\mathcal{R}\in\mathcal{D}_{k}$ such that $\mathcal{Q}\subseteq\mathcal{R}$.

I fail to see why such a statement is valid. He also mentioned that this is a stopping time argument, perhaps the labeling does not matter that much, what bothers me is the maximality argument.

There are several facts regarding the properties of $\mathcal{D}_{k}$. The union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\mathcal{D}_{k}$ of all $\mathcal{D}_{k}$ contains all the dyadic cubes in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, this is not too hard to check. Besides that, if $\mathcal{Q}\in\mathcal{D}_{k}$ for some $k$, then $\mathcal{Q}\in\mathcal{D}_{j}$ for all $j\ne k$, this is easy to check. So the crucial question is that, why the following cannot hold?
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{Q}_{1}\subseteq\mathcal{Q}_{2}\subseteq\cdots\mathcal{Q}_{i}\subseteq\cdots,
\end{align*}
each $\mathcal{Q}_{i}\in\mathcal{D}_{k}$ and the chain does not terminate. We know that for any dyadic cubes $\mathcal{Q},\mathcal{R}$, either they are disjoint or they contain each other: $\mathcal{Q}\subseteq\mathcal{R}$ or $\mathcal{R}\subseteq\mathcal{Q}$. So if the chain does not terminate, then there is no such maximal dyadic cube.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any additional information about the function $S(x)$ available? In this generality, this is surely false. For example, if $S(x)=4$ for all $x$, then $\Omega_1=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\Omega_2=\varnothing$, and so $\mathcal{D}_1$ is the family of all dyadic cubes.

On the other hand, if you know that all $\Omega_k$ have finite measure (for example when $S\in L^1$), then the dyadic cubes in $\mathcal{D}_k$ cannot be arbitrarily large: if a cube $Q$ is big enough, then
$$|Q|> 2|\Omega_{k}|\ge 2|\Omega_{k}\cap Q|,$$
and so $Q\notin \mathcal{D}_k$. In other words, the condition $|Q\cap\Omega_{k}|\ge \frac{1}{2}|Q|$ implies an upper bound on the size of $Q$.